# Extract dynamically created form data

Tags: php, jquery

I've just started using jQuery. One thing I've been using it for is adding rows to a table that is part of a form.

When I add a new row, I give all the form elements names like `'name_' + rowNumber`. I increment `rowNumber` each time I add a row.

I also usually have a Remove Row Button. Even when a row is removed, the `rowNumber` count stays the same to keep from repeating element names.

When the form is submitted, I set a hidden element to equal the `rowNumber` value from jQuery. Then in PHP, I count from 1 to the `rowNumber` value. Then for each value, I perform an `isset($_REQUEST['name'_ . index])`. This is how I extract the form elements that remained after deleting rows in jQuery.

Does anyone here have a better technique for accounting for deleted rows?

Comment: don't use REQUEST, use GET or POST.

Comment: Thanks. I just did a little research and understand why.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For some of our simpler tables, we use a field name such as 'name[]', though for JavaScript they would need a usable id.

It does add some complexity in that 'name[0]' has to assume 'detail[0]' is the correct element.

PHP will create an array and append elements if the field name ends with [] similar to

```
<input name="field[]" value="first value" />
<input name="field[]" value="second value" />

// is roughly the same as

$_POST['field'][] = 'first value';
$_POST['field'][] = 'second value';
```

Comment: So I could set name="field[]" id="field_1" is this what you mean?

Comment: @Lee you can, but why do you need the row id at all?

Comment: One project I had to calculate the values from all the elements in a particular column. Basically I used the same technique in jQuery as I described using in PHP to get existing elements.

Comment: Why not just give all your inputs and/or rows a className, and loop through them that way? There are enough `getElementsByClassName` functions out there, and *most* of them work perfectly...

Answer (score 2):

Use arrays to hold you values in your submission. So bin the row count at the client side, and name your new elements like `name[]`. This means that `$_POST['name']` will be an array.

That way at the server side you can easily get the row count (if you need it) with:

```
$rowcount = count($_POST['name']);
```

...and you can loop through the rows at the server side like this:

```
for ($i = 0; isset($_POST['name'][$i]; $i++) {}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could extract all the rows by doing a foreach($_POST as $key => $value).

Comment: Hello, Nice idea. However, the form often contains data outside the table with unique names.

Comment: it doesn't matter you can parse the $key value and see which input it is. $key will return values like "name_1", "name_2" "unique_1" ,...

Comment: This method will give you all the form fields, including those with unique names. If you want to use this method only for the form elements (sans parsing within the loop) you can use `foreach(array_keys($_POST, "name_") as $key)` and then using `$_POST[$key]`

Answer (score 1):

When adding a dynamic form element use the array naming method. for example

```
<input type="text" name="textfield[]" />
```

When the form is posted the `textfield[]` will be a PHP array, you can use it easily then.
When you remove an element make sure its removed from the HTML DOM.

Answer (score 0):

Like blejzz suggests, I think if you use $_GET, then you can just cycle through all of the inputs that were sent, ignoring the deleted rows.

```
foreach ($_GET as $k=>$v) {
      echo "KEY: ".$k."; VALUE: ".$v."<BR>";
}
```

I notice that you mention "accounting for deleted rows"; you could include a hidden input, and add a unique value to it each time someone deletes a row.  For example, the input could hold comma-separated values of the row numbers:

```
<input type="hidden" value="3,5,8" id="deletions" />
```

and include in your jQuery script:

```
$('.delete').click(function(){
      var num = //whatever your method for getting the row number
      var v = $('#deletions').val();
      v = v.split(',');
      v.push(num);
      v = v.join(',');
      $('#deletions').val(v);
});
```

Then you should be able to know which rows were deleted (if that is what you were looking for).

Answer (score 0):

you can use POST or GET

After submit you can use all of your form element with this automaticly. You dont need to reorganise your form element names. Even you dont need to know form elements names.

```
<form method="POST" id="fr" name="fr">.....</form>

<?php
if(isset($_POST['fr'])){  
     foreach($_POST as $data){
          echo $data;
     }
}
?>
```

Also you should look this
[grafanimasyon.blogspot.com.tr/2015/02/veritabanndan-php-form-olusturucu.html](http://grafanimasyon.blogspot.com.tr/2015/02/veritabanndan-php-form-olusturucu.html)

This is a automated form creator calcutating your database tables. You can see how to give name to form elements and use them.